# My turtle color wont fill in python 3

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
From turtle import *
clicker = Turtle()
clicker.color('green')
clicker.begin_fill()
clicker.forward(100// render)
clicker.right(90)
clicker.forward(100 // render)
clicker.right(90)
clicker.forward(100// render)
clicker.right(90)
clicker.forward(100 // render)
clicker.right(90)
clicker.end_fill()
clicker.color('orange')
```

i have multiple turtles that is why i defined it as clicker and i have already drawn in this postion but im trying to draw over this postion and i get no syntax errors its a logical error

Comment: Works fine for me (draws a filled green square) once I change `From` to `from` and remove the `// render` junk

Comment: We can't diagnose the problem just from this partial code. Post the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

This program is fine if you define an appropriate `render` as an integer. And use `from` lowercase.

Comment: I doubt either of those are the actual problem. If they were, the OP would have gotten an error, but he says he isn't getting one.

Comment: Maybe the OP doesn't think to mention it, I mean he's the type of person to misspell keywords.

Comment: I'd agree with you if he didn't mention anything about errors, but he explicitly said "i get no syntax errors its a logical error". (I'm assuming that he thinks that _any_ kind of exception is a syntax error- a common misconception among new users)

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle

clicker = turtle.Turtle()
clicker.color('green')
clicker.begin_fill()
clicker.forward(100)
clicker.right(90)
clicker.forward(100)
clicker.right(90)
clicker.forward(100)
clicker.right(90)
clicker.forward(100)
clicker.right(90)
clicker.end_fill()
clicker.color('orange')
```

works fine according to: http://www.skulpt.org/

All I did was remove the // render and change your import statement.

Comment: I doubt either of those are the actual problem. If they were, the OP would have gotten an error, but he says he isn't getting one.